# Find if a point lies within the angle formed by three other points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have three points (A, B, C) in a 3d space that define an angle like this:

[image]

I need a fast way to know if another point D (that I already know is coplanar with the plane ABC) lies within the angle formed by <ABC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express vector AD as a linear combination of AB and AC.  If the coefficients of the linear combination are both positive, then D is inside the angle.

So basically, you are solving the system of equations (3 equations, 2 unknowns):

$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
b_x-a_x & c_x-a_x& d_x-a_x \\
b_y-a_y & c_y-a_y& d_y-a_y \\
b_z-a_z & c_z-a_z& d_z-a_z \\
\end{array}\right]
$

which represent the following equations:

$
(b_x-a_x) \times I + (c_x-a_x) \times J = d_x-a_x \\
(b_y-a_y) \times I + (c_y-a_y) \times J = d_y-a_y \\
(b_z-a_z) \times I + (c_z-a_z) \times J = d_z-a_z \\
$

and if your solution vector has positive components ($I>0, J>0$), then D is inside that angle.  If there is no solution, then D is not in the ABC plane.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $d_y-a_y$ and $d_z-a_z$ on the right side?

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  I've fixed the typo, thanks!

Comment: I really don't know how to solve that... *shame*... I know D is in the plane, so there exists a solution, but how would I arrive to that, IDK... I'm not used to that notation.

Comment: I've added the 3 basic equations, now you just have to solve for I and J.

Comment: Oh ok, now I see, thanks!

Comment: hi , i tried to do above for 2d geometry . say d=757,-353 a=588,-352 b=445,-239 c=702,-254 . To my surprise , i got both coefficient of linear combination as positive , then I plotted them at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mhq4hsncnh and found d to be outside . why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

Precompute $v = C - A$, and let $w = (-v_y, v_x)$. Then $D$ is on the right side of $AC$ if and only iff $(D - A) \cdot w > 0$. A similar construction tells you whether $D$ is on the upper side of $AB$. So in that case, you need to check $(D-A) \cdot w' < 0$. If you pass both those tests, then $D$ is in the wedge.

(This assumes that $B$ is on the 'right side" of $AC$, i.e., $(B- A) 
\cdot w > 0$. If that's not the case, you need to swap $B$ and $C$.).

Comment: How would you do that in 3D? I'm curious because of $w = (-v_y, v_x)$

Comment: Ah...we're in 3-space. Then let $n = (C - A) \times (B - A)$, and let $w = n \times (C - A)$ and $w' = n \times (B - A)$. Then, if you're applying this to many points $D$, you have only two dot products to compute, rather than trying to solve a degenerate $3 \times 3$ system of equations as you need to do in @jh314's solution.

Comment: Thank you @John Hughes. I will try out this method as it would be faster and easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Project the points onto one of the coordinate planes and test
$$
AC \times AD > 0 \text{ and } AD \times AB > 0
$$
(use the projected points here; $\times$ is the 2D cross product, a number)